# AngularJS watch can't detect input range ng-model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, font-size

Got my directive like that

```
<input type="range" min="10" max="100" ng-model="svgConfig.textConfig.fontSize" />
```

In my controller I got object like

```
$scope.svgConfig = {
    text:'',
    textConfig: {
        fontSize: 20
    },
    rectConfig: []
};
```

Trying to catch changes here, in link for directive, but nothing happens.

```
var setDomBindings = function($scope, $element, $attrs){

    $scope.$watch('svgConfig.textConfig.fontSize', function() {
        var domText = $element.find('text'),
            textExample = domText.last()[0],
            dataText = $scope.svgConfig.text;

        debugger; //haven't even been reached! 

        if($.isEmptyObject(textExample) && domText.length === 0 && dataText === 0){
            $scope.clearSvgRectConfig();
            return;
        }

        $scope.setSvgRectConfig(textExample, domText.length);
    });
};

/*
* Retruns initialized DOM element
*/
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: './app/shared/imageTextEditor/imageTxtSvgView.html',
    controller: 'imageTxtSvgController',
    transclude: true,
    link: setDomBindings
};
```

Comment: your binding is on `svgConfig.textConfig.fontSize` but your watch is on `svgConfig.fontSize`.  is this a typo or a bad translation of your code into the question body?

Comment: @Claies typo, sorry

Comment: ok, now that that's cleared up, your `$watch` has a weird syntax, and you appear to be using `$element` which isn't an angular aware function.

Comment: @Claies I can make it work by catching `change` from range element and set value to scope, and doing apply after, but too many applies make my app throwing errors in console with the speed of light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that this function will not find elements by tag name / CSS selector. For lookups by tag name, try instead angular.element(document).find(...) or $document.find(), or use the standard DOM APIs, e.g. document.querySelectorAll()
You do have access to children(), contents(), and data() implementations, so you can usually find a way around it.

Comment: well,yep, I could make it work like through element events, but, ahh... don't really like to doing stuff with DOM.
maybe I miss something, there are a lot of other code there also, which applying changes to scope

Comment: if you add jquery with angular then you can use that function.

Comment: already got it there. i guess I'll make your post as answer if nothing new interesting will be here : )